# PHPMyAdmin is showing error "Uncaught TypeError"

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, xampp

2 days ago, I worked with my laptop (Windows 10) and suddenly my PHPMyAdmin can't show databases.

This is for xampp 7.3.7 version. In the past, I've tried the oldest version and it works.
I end up changing it because of the same error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to PhpMyAdmin\Core::arrayWrite() must be of the type array, null given,
called in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Config.php on line 1049 and
defined in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Core.php:677 

Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Config.php(1049): PhpMyAdmin\Core::arrayWrite('lang', NULL, 'id')
#1 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Config.php(996): PhpMyAdmin\Config->setUserValue(NULL, 'lang', 'id', 'en')
#2 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\common.inc.php(455): PhpMyAdmin\Config->loadUserPreferences()
#3 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\index.php(27): require_once('C:\xampp\phpMyA...')
#4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Core.php on line 677
```

From the other similar question, the answer said that I have to clear browser cache about "pma", but it doesn't work for my problem.

Comment: what are your last changes in your config.php file?

Comment: I didn't do anything to the config.php file. It suddenly appeared in my phpMyAdmin